# file disappearing from SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, fileinfo

I have a problem creating a text file on SD card to be attached to an email to be sent with gmail application.
When attached to an email in the gmail app, the email stalls in the red "Sending..." state forever. The file is created using createCSVfile() below.

Debugging my code, launching my app different times, csv_file.exists() always returns false, as if the file is not found and to be created each time the app is run.
However, using a file manager I can see file is there between and during runs.

Any help please?
Thanks

```
File csv_file = null;
String createCSVfile() {
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        csv_file = new File( getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "InOutStats.txt");
        if (csv_file != null ) {
            if( csv_file.exists() ){
                Log.v("CSV_FILE", "Stat file " + csv_file.toString() +" already there!");
            }else{
                csv_file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                try {
                    boolean bool = csv_file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            FileWriter fWriter = null;
            try {
                fWriter = new FileWriter(csv_file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
            try {
                writer.write("Some text here!!! " + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                writer.newLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }else{
        Log.v("CSV_FILE", "NO SD CARD HERE???");
    }
    return csv_file.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

which should be

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())
```

I saw only two very minor "errors":

[Style issue]

```
csv_file = new File( getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "InOutStats.txt");
```

should be

```
csv_file = new File( getExternalFilesDir(null), "InOutStats.txt");
```

because otherwise you are using `File.toString()`.

[Smallest code]

Removed should be:

```
csv_file.createNewFile();
```

---

***Second attempt***

Try replacing

```
    if (csv_file != null ) {
        if( csv_file.exists() ){
            Log.v("CSV_FILE", "Stat file " + csv_file.toString() +" already there!");
        }else{
            csv_file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            try {
                boolean bool = csv_file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

with

```
     {
```

This removes the existence test, mkdirs and unneeded separate file creation.
Done to try restrict the error area.

Furthermore you are using the default platform encoding for the text; you could make it explicit:

```
new FileWriter(csv_file, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Hi. I applied the two changes as you suggest, but everything is the same. In fact, the same problem happened when I was only printing a static String into the file and new File() can be given the whole path.

Comment: Hi again. Very strange. I tested the same code in other two phones, and the email is sent out correctly. Not sure what is going on. Thanks

Comment: Maybe the physical file system was buffered, not directly written to disk / SD card. Good idea of testing on other phones.

Comment: Hi Joop. File is on disk, in the right place. I can read it with a file manager even when app is not running. Phone is a ZTE blade (kinda cheap hardware, I know).